# What is the best way to connect to a DotNet web service from java?

Tags: java, .net, web-services, wsdl

We have a dotnet web service that a java using customer wants to connect to.  What is the best technology for them to use?  Axis or Metro, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically you could do this with any standards compliant framework. In practice, the generated code (with the default settings) by some tools may not work for you. You may need for example to modify a namespace or add a SOAP header. You can do this for example with Axis2 and CXF, but some extra configuration is needed.

I would recommend CXF over Axis2, because I think it's easier to configure. It also requires fewer megabytes of jar files to re-distribute.

Answer (score 3):

WSDL is a standard language following the protocol in a correct way the technology shouldn't mind.

only if this implementation requires to meet the time to market of your client. in that case use the one that can be implement more quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I've had success connecting to a .Net service with Apache Axis2

Answer (score 1):

I haven't use Metro, but with Axis is very easy connect to .Net services

Answer (score 1):

sun and MS have been doing expensive interop tests with the MS framework and SUN's metro. Axis and Axis2 have been having decent interop with MS framework from the beginning BUT if you want completely tested interop then, go for Metro.

BR,
~A